# Returning value from any class method if condition not true

Tags: php

OOP & functions newbie here

How would I return a value if in one of the methods in my class, the value is not true? I want to be able to execute each method in a class and return a value if the condition is untrue in that method otherwise execute next method.

I thought this may be better than calling each method from the index page.

I want to do a more complicated login class but am using this example script to practice.

I do not get the returned value 'Boo' or 'neither'. I only get 'moo' if I enter Moo.

The only way I know to start the process would be $word_check = $words->test1();
and because of that it would only return a value for the test1 method I think.

How do I start the process so I can achieve what I need?

**Index Page**

```
<?php
require_once('Classes/words.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {    
$word_check = $words->test1();
if ($word_check !== true) {    
$the_message = $word_check;    
} else {    
header('Location: main.php');
}
}
?>  
<form action="" method="post">    
<label>Word</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="word" value="<?php echo $word; ?>" >    
<h4 class="bg-danger"><?php echo $the_message; ?></h4>    
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

**Words Class**

```
<?php
Class Words {    
public $word;
function __construct() {    
$this->word = trim($_POST['word']);
}
public function test1() {
if ($this->word == 'Moo') {    
return "Moo";    
} else {    
$this->test2();    
}
}
public function test2() {    
if ($this->word == 'Boo') {    
return "Boo";    
} else {    
return "Neither!";    
}
}
}
$words = new Words();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**test2()** function returns value but in the call `$this->test2();` in the function **test1()** will not return anything until you use return keyword. So solution is `return $this->test2();`

Comment: Works like a dream! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
Make it one function

public function test1() {

    if ($this->word == 'Moo') {
        return "Moo";
    } 
    if ($this->word == 'Boo') {
        return "Boo";
    }
    return "Neither!";
    }
```

Comment: I could and maybe my words example could have been better but I want to know how to return a value from a function if its not the one I called at the start with word_check = $words->test1();. If I say $this->test2() in test1 function to go to test2 function, how do I get the test2 return value on index page?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to create object of

> Words

Then only constructor will call you , you will get value in $this->word

```
require_once('Classes/words.php');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// creating object time constructor will call
$words = new Words();
$word_check = $words->test1();

if ($word_check !== true) {

  $the_message = $word_check;

} else {

  header('Location: main.php');

}
}
```

Comment: I created the object at the bottom of my words class page?

Comment: change if ($word_check !== true)  to  if ($word_check === false) its working

Comment: return $this->test2(); was the winner